# Change the private key for my .onion domain

Tags: onion-routing, private-key

I have a .onion site. Is it possible to change the private key on my existing domain?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Right now it is unclear to me what you want to do.

Comment: Just a thought: Why would you want to use a new private key but keep the .onion address? If someone else has your private key, then this would not help. Even if you could brute-force a different private key that hashes to the same .onion address, it would not stop the other person from doing anything they can do if you just keep the same key: either way, they have as much control over the .onion as you do. So if you need a new private key, you don't need just any old key, but one that yields a different .onion address.

Answer (score 3):

Your host name is calculated from your private key.
If you change your private key, you will get a new host name.

Comment: After reading your comment I wondered how to do this and found a oneliner on https://swehack.org/viewtopic.php?f=37&p=6978: 
`U=$(openssl rsa -in a.pem -pubout -outform DER | tail -c +23 | shasum | head -c 20 | python -c "import base64,sys; print base64.b32encode(sys.stdin.readline().strip('\n').decode('hex')).lower()"); echo "http://${U}.onion"`